# UnHandled exception error in C

Tags: c, out-of-memory

I just finished to build my class-homework but when I run the code I get an error.
First error appears in line 52:

```
size = GetAndSetStd(x);
```

Then I press continue and the program keeps working until line number 88:

```
 *x = (student *)malloc( size * sizeof(student) );
```

The final error I got it's this one:

`Unhandled exception at 0x011f162b in Test01.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcccccccc.`

As you can see I have allocated enough memory for it so I don't know what is the problem in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct{
    int id;
    char lname[16];
    char fname[11];
    unsigned a[3];
    int flag;
}student;

int GetAndSetStd (student **x);
/*Function name:GetAndSetStd
Description : Function asks the user the number of students receiving data from the students.
Input:  A double pointer to a student struct and  size of the array
Output: size - size of the students in the array
Algorithm: First we get the size of the stuedents array from the user,Second Allocate memory for the array and by a for loop getting the info from the soruce text file..*/
void PrintArray (student *x,int size);
/*Function name:PrintArray
Description : The function prints the students on the screen array
Input:  A pointer to a student struct and  size of the array
Output: none
Algorithm: By a for loop the function prints the array of students.*/
student * MaxAvg(student *x,int size);
/*Function name:MaxAvg
Description : Students function accepts an array returns the address structure of the student with the highest average score.
Input:  A pointer to a student struct and  size of the array
Output: Address the structure of the student with the highest average score.
Algorithm: By a for loop the function calculates the avg score of the student and checks if it's higher than the next score .if it is higher it's save the index of the score and when the FOR loop is finished return the address of the index.*/
float StdAvg(student *x); 
/*Function name:StdAvg
Description : The function gets a pointer to the student and calculate the grades average score.
Input:  A pointer to a student in the struct
Output: returns the average grade score.
Algorithm: The function calculates the sum of the three grades of the student and then divide by the number of grades .the function returns the average score of the student.*/
void ChangeRandStd (student *x,int size);
/*Function name:ChangeRandStd
Description : The function gets the array of students and length of it, taking a random student and replaces the flag field value from 1 to 0.
Input: A pointer to a student struct and  size of the array
Output: none
Algorithm: By DO WHILE loop, using rand function  in the loop. we pick a random student and checks if the flag field is 1,unless keep searching for flag field value=1. after finding it change the value of flag field from 1 to 0.*/
int CopyToAnotherGroup (student *x,int size,student **arr);
void Get_Lost(char* str);
int main()
 { student **x,**y,*p,temp;
   int size,n=1,len;
     size=GetAndSetStd(x);
     while(n)
     {
         printf("Press 1 to see all students\n");
         printf("Press 2 to see two students with biggest average\n");
         printf("Press 3 to change flag for random student\n");
         printf("Press 4 to see all students from the new group\n");
         printf("Press 0 to exit\n");
         printf("enter your choise:");
         scanf("%d",&n);
         switch(n)
         {
         case 1: PrintArray(*x,size);break;
         case 2: PrintArray(p=MaxAvg(*x,size),1);
             temp=*p;
             *p=*x[size-1];
             *x[size-1]=temp;
             PrintArray(MaxAvg(*x,size-1),1);
             break;
         case 3: ChangeRandStd(*x,size);
             break;
         case 4: len=CopyToAnotherGroup(*x,size,y);
             PrintArray(*y,len);
         }
     }
     free(*x);
     free(*y);
     system("pause");
     return 0;
 }
 int GetAndSetStd (student **x)
 { int size,i;
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("list.txt","r");
     printf("Please enter the number of the students:");
     scanf("%d",&size);
     *x=(student *)malloc(size*sizeof(student));
     if(!x)
         Get_Lost("no memmory");
     for (i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
     {
         fscanf(f,"%d%s%s%u%u%u",(*x)[i].id,(*x)[i].lname,(*x)[i].fname,(*x)[i].a[0],(*x)[i].a[1],(*x)[i].a[2]);
         (*x)[i].flag=1;
     }
     fclose(f);
     return size;
 }
 void PrintArray (student *x,int size)
 {
     int i;
     for (i=0 ; i<size ; i++ )
     {
         printf("%d,%s,%s,%d,%d,%d,%d",x[i].id,x[i].lname,x[i].fname,x[i].flag,x[i].a[0],x[i].a[1],x[i].a[2]);
     }
 }
 float StdAvg(student *x)
 {
     int sum=0;
     float avg=0;
     sum=(*x).a[0]+(*x).a[1]+(*x).a[2];
     avg=sum/3.0;
     return avg;

 }
 student * MaxAvg(student *x,int size)
 {
     float max_avg=StdAvg(x);
     int i,index=0;
     for(i=1 ; i<size ; i++ )
        {
            if(StdAvg(x+i)>max_avg)
            {
                max_avg=StdAvg(x+i);
                index=i;

            }
        }
     return x+i;
 }
 void ChangeRandStd (student *x,int size)
 {
     int temp;
     do
     {
         temp=0+rand()%(size);
     }while(x[temp].flag!=0);
     x[temp].flag=0;

 }
 int CopyToAnotherGroup (student *x,int size,student **arr)
 {
     int i,count=0;
     for ( i=0 ; i< size ; i++ )
     {
         if(x[i].flag==0)
         {
             count++;
             *arr=(student*)realloc(arr,count*sizeof(student));
             if(!*arr)
                 Get_Lost("no memmory");
             (*arr)[count-1]=x[i];
         }
     }
     return count;
 }
 void Get_Lost(char* str)
{
    printf("\n%s",str);
        exit(1);
}
```

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your declaration and usage of `x` in `main()`. You should be declaring a single-indirection pointer and passing its *address* instead:

```
student *x = NULL;

GetAndSetStd(&x);
```

And update the remainder of your code accordingly (which will be a *lot* of changes, but thats the price for writing this much code without seeing if it was actually correct incrementally). As-written you're passing a pointer value that is indeterminate and dereferencing for-write it within the called function. And before you ask, yes, `y` has similar problems.

The rest I leave to you (and Aniket has already pointed out your incorrect invocation of `fscanf`).

Answer (score 1):

Like `scanf`, `fscanf()` also expects you to pass in the address of the variables to store the input data. You don't have it on the `fscanf()` line.. which can be the source of your segfault.

The error basically means that you are accessing a memory location that you are not authorized.

```
     fscanf(f,"%d%s%s%u%u%u",(*x)[i].id,(*x)[i].lname,(*x)[i].fname,(*x)[i].a[0],(*x)[i].a[1],(*x)[i].a[2]);
```

should be:

```
     fscanf(f,"%d%s%s%u%u%u",(*x)[i].id,(*x)[i].lname,(*x)[i].fname,&((*x)[i].a[0]),&((*x)[i].a[1]),&((*x)[i].a[2])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you help guys. 
WhozCraig:
I have to send a double pointer to some of the functions not a single pointer.This is what our teacher ask for :|